# While debugging a springboot project , eclipse always asks to "Select Java Application" -- Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application in eclipse which works perfectly fine. If I want to debug my springboot application, I right click the project and **Debug As --> Java Application** . This opens a dialogue box as below:

[image]

Why does eclipse ask me every single time to select a "**Main**" class? I have already created a debug configuration for the project and specified the main class. See below image.

[image]

If I right click on the main class and Debug As --> Java Application, the program runs just fine without asking for any additional information.

The question is: I want eclipse to debug my application without asking me to "Select a Java Application" with main class if I right click on my project and Debug As --> Java Application -- because I have already specified this in "Launch Configuration". How can this be achieved?

Comment: Right-clicking the project is not the right thing for that. Use the _Debug_ button in the main toolbar, _Find Actions_ (Ctrl+3) or the new _Launch Configuration_ view instead. If you want to use the _Debug_ (F11) command, you might consider setting in the preferences _Run/Debug > Launching_ the option _Launch Operation_ to _Always launch the previously launched application_.

Comment: @howlger - Thanks for the information. I knew the preferences that you mentioned. I was curious why eclipse behaved that way and if we could set a main class for the project so that the project always launched the same main class without asking for a main type.